# How can I run a regex against a filename?

Tags: regex, bash

In a list of files:

```
javascript-custom-rules-plugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
README.txt
sonar-build-breaker-plugin-2.0.jar
sonar-javascript-plugin-2.11.jar
tmo-custom-rules-1.0.jar
```

I am attempting to match these filenames by regex.

**My Script**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

install_location=/usr/local/sonar/extensions/plugins

for f in $(ls -1 $install_location)
do
    # remove any previous versions of this plugin
    if [[ "$f" =~ ".*tmo-custom-rules-(.+)\.jar" ]]
    then
        echo "found $f. will remove"
    else
        echo "$f doesn't match"
    fi
done
```

I've tried `if [[ "$f" =~ ".*tmo-custom-rules-(.+)\.jar" ]]` and `if [[ "$f" == *"tmo-custom-rules" ]]` to no avail.

I'm getting

```
javascript-custom-rules-plugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar doesn't match
README.txt doesn't match
sonar-build-breaker-plugin-2.0.jar doesn't match
sonar-javascript-plugin-2.11.jar doesn't match
tmo-custom-rules-1.0.jar doesn't match
```

when I expect `found tmo-custom-rules-1.0.jar. will remove`

I've run my regular expression through many regular expression testers with the data above, and they all return the correct matches, but I can't get it to work here in my script.

*How can I loop through, and check to see if any files matches this regular expression?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In BASH regex **must be** unquoted so this should work:

```
[[ $f =~ .*tmo-custom-rules-(.+)\.jar ]]
```

Or better:

```
re=".*tmo-custom-rules-(.+)\.jar"
[[ $f =~ $re ]]
```

However you don't even need regex and can use shell glob matching:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

install_location=/usr/local/sonar/extensions/plugins

for f in "$install_location"/*
do
    # remove any previous versions of this plugin
    if [[ $f == *tmo-custom-rules-*.jar ]]
    then
        echo "found $f. will remove"
    else
        echo "$f doesn't match"
    fi
done
```

Note that you can avoid using output of `ls` which is not always fit for scripting.

Comment: works perfectly.  i left my `for` statement alone, and unquoted `$f`.  glob matching works just as i wanted.   thanks!  +1 for the regex solution as well, for my question. i'll use the glob matching.

Comment: That's not a regular expression but a shell filename pattern. Maybe that's what the original poster really wants?

Comment: edited my comment, @RobDavis, thanks.  anubhava also provided a solution to regex, but merely offered an alternative. either way - they both work

Comment: could you explain the `"$install_location"/*` bit?  i don't recognize this behavior

Comment: nevermind.. using logic - i see whats happening.  you are just using another filename pattern.  All files within `$install_location`.

Comment: `"$install_location"/*` is also glob that expands to all files/directories of `"$install_location"`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `expr` using the colon operator:

```
if expr "$f" : '.*tmo-custom-rules-.*\.jar' > /dev/null; then
    echo matches
fi
```

Note that the regular expressions in this context are assumed to be anchored to the start of the line.

Comment: ok, yours also worked, but didn't with my `(.+)` constraint.  any idea why?

Comment: It doesn't work with extended regular expressions, and plus is only valid in extended regular expressions. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html